# SYSTEM ERROR: NumberFormatException: Zero length BigInteger

Tags: apache-drill

This error often appears when I try to CTAS from CSV data.

CSV Schema:

```sql
create or replace schema
(
    `SomeCol1` BIGINT NOT NULL,
    `SomeCol2` INT NOT NULL,
    `SomeCol3` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `SomeCol4` DATE NOT NULL FORMAT 'yyyy-MM-dd',
    `SomeCol5` INT,
    `SomeCol6` INT NOT NULL,
    `SomeCol7` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    `SomeCol8` DECIMAL (10,2) NOT NULL,
    `SomeCol9` DOUBLE
)
for table  "<path to CSVs>"
properties ('drill.strict' = 'true')
```

Then I run:

```sql
create table "<path to a parquet>" as select
    <all 9 columns>
    from "<path to CSVs>"
```

In some cases this error happens:

> SYSTEM ERROR: NumberFormatException: Zero length BigInteger
>
> Fragment 0:0
>
> Please, refer to logs for more information. *

**) There is nothing more in the logs.*

---

There are gigabytes of rows in the CSV and some of them are obviously in some bad shape.

1) **How I'm supposed to find such error?** At least on which column it happened? (except some hacks like reducing the count of columns and then rows, etc ..)

2) Is there some option to increase verbosity?

3) Or can I adjust the schema for .. better behavior?